# hy , i have to draw some picture i need help thx

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis}; % x axis
  \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[anchor=south east] {y axis}; % y axis  
  \draw (0.0,1) -- (-22pt,-17.9pt) -- (21.9pt,-17.9pt) -- cycle;  
  \node (A) at (0.05,1.05) {A};
  \node (B) at (0.9,-0.6) {D};
  \node (C) at (-0.9,-0.6) {C};
  \node (O) at (0.03 , 0.02) {O}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You just dumped some code without explaining what problem you have. At least explain what you're trying to correct, or provide a screenshot of the picture you got so far.

Comment: When you edit your question to add the missing information, please also rewrite the title so that it is a description of your question. This will help future users with the same problem to find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome among us. This website isn't a "draw for me" place. You have to formulate a question about something you struggle to do and show what you tried and ask if it could be done better/easier..

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment, but this at least covers most of the first drawing.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \draw (0,0) circle (5);
  \draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis}; 
  \draw[->] (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5) node[anchor=south east] {y axis}; 

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A) at (90:5);
  \coordinate (B) at (-90:5);
  \coordinate (C) at (90+120:5);
  \coordinate (D) at (90-120:5);
  \coordinate (E) at ($(B)+(-5,0)$);

  \node[below] at (B) {B};
  \node[above right] at (O) {O};
  
  \draw[very thick] (A) node[above] {A}
  --(C) node[below left] {C}
  --(D) node[below right] {D}
  --cycle;

  \draw (E) arc (180:30:5);

  \foreach \n in {A,C,D}{
    \draw[fill=white] (\n) circle (1mm);
  }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such a nice suggestion, hats off